# My Password Checker using Tkinter is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

Tried to use Tkinter and customtkinter to make a Password checker of sorts, Even with the correct Username and Password, I get Access Denied. I tried using several different ways and methods and I tried to do it without Tkinter and It worked fine, Idk why its not working

```
`import tkinter
import customtkinter
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from pyttsx3 import *

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System") 
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue") 


app = customtkinter.CTk() 
app.geometry("1920x1080")
app.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
app.title('Login')
n=0
USRd={"Goop": "S311","Drep": "S456"}

img1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Wallpaper.png"))
l1=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=app,image=img1)
l1.pack()

frame=customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=l1, width=320, height=360, corner_radius=15)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

l2=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Log into your Account",font=('Century Gothic',20))
l2.place(x=50, y=45)

user = customtkinter.StringVar(value='')
entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(
    master=frame,
    width=220,
    placeholder_text='Username',
    textvariable=user,
)
entry1.place(x=50, y=110)
user=entry1.get()

passw = customtkinter.StringVar(value='')
entry2=customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=220, placeholder_text='Password', textvariable=passw)
entry2.place(x=50, y=165)
passw=entry2.get()

def button_function():
    for k in USRd:
        if (user==k) and (passw==USRd[k]):
            speak("Access Granted")
            x="Welcome back", k, "You have", USRd[k],"Notifications"
            speak(x)
            app.destroy()
            w = customtkinter.CTk()
            w.geometry("1280x720")
            w.title('Welcome')
            l1=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text=x ,font=('Century Gothic',60))
            l1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5,  anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
            w.mainloop()
        else:
            speak("Access Nope")

button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, width=220, text="Login", command=button_function, corner_radius=6)
button1.place(x=50, y=240)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.mainloop()`
```

Comment: I don't believe that this works correctly without TKinter. Your `for` loop will print `nope` for every user in `USRd` that isn't equal to the selected user.

Comment: You're setting `user=entry1.get()` before the user has a chance to fill in the entry, and doing the same thing for the password. Why aren't you using the `StringVar` that you created a few lines earlier?

Comment: There's no need to loop through the dictionary. You should do `if user in USRd and passw == USRd[user]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .get,
so the code should look like this :-

```
def button_function():
    user=entry1.get()
    passw=entry2.get()
    for k in USRd:
        if (user==k) and (passw==USRd[k]):
            speak("Access Granted")
            x="Welcome back", k, "You have", USRd[k],"Notifications"
            speak(x)
            app.destroy()
            w = customtkinter.CTk()
            w.geometry("1280x720")
            w.title('Welcome')
            l1=customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text=x ,font=('Century Gothic',60))
            l1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5,  anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
            w.mainloop()
        else:
            speak("Access Nope")
```

Comment: I tried this before, It didn't work. I replaced user and pass with entry1.get() and entry2.get() and it worked

Comment: @Phoenixstudies It didn't work because you wanted to retrieve the values of the variables before it was entered.

Comment: @Phoenixstudies You can continue using `user.get()` but just change the variable name: `user_name = user.get()` and `pass_w = passw.get()`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Found an Answer for it, I was using the .get() function in the wrong way apparently. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).